# Multi-Dimensional PHP Array Into HTML Table

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, dns

I'm trying to display all of the DNS records for specific domains in an HTML table.

Here's the current code that's showing me the records:

```
<?php
$dns = dns_get_record("stackoverflow.com");
print_r($dns);
?>
```

I want to display the data in an HTML table, like you can see in the DNS Report section here:  https://stackoverflow.com.websiteoutlook.com/

There should be 5 columns.  These 4 variables are in each DNS record:  Host, Type, Class, TTL.  Then each record will have one or more "extra" variables that I want to display like the link above does.

I've read some tutorials about doing looping through with `foreach` statements.  However, all the examples I can see either have hardcoded variables, are multi-level arrays, or don't have "extra" fields that may exist in some of the arrays but not others.

Any help on how to generate this table would be greatly appreciated.

Sample Output of `$dns` as requested:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => A
        [ip] => 151.101.1.69
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => A
        [ip] => 151.101.65.69
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => A
        [ip] => 151.101.129.69
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => A
        [ip] => 151.101.193.69
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 172800
        [type] => NS
        [target] => ns-358.awsdns-44.com
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 172800
        [type] => NS
        [target] => ns-1033.awsdns-01.org
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 172800
        [type] => NS
        [target] => ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 172800
        [type] => NS
        [target] => ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 21600
        [type] => SOA
        [mname] => ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com
        [rname] => cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com
        [serial] => 1
        [refresh] => 21600
        [retry] => 3600
        [expire] => 259200
        [minimum-ttl] => 300
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => MX
        [pri] => 1
        [target] => aspmx.l.google.com
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => MX
        [pri] => 5
        [target] => alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => MX
        [pri] => 5
        [target] => alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => MX
        [pri] => 10
        [target] => alt3.aspmx.l.google.com
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => MX
        [pri] => 10
        [target] => alt4.aspmx.l.google.com
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => TXT
        [txt] => MS=ms52592611
        [entries] => Array
            (
                [0] => MS=ms52592611
            )
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => TXT
        [txt] => google-site-verification=ctogLnZNAdc_CXq8yOhODMLpmugGynjxKecKHDz4oL8
        [entries] => Array
            (
                [0] => google-site-verification=ctogLnZNAdc_CXq8yOhODMLpmugGynjxKecKHDz4oL8
            )
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => TXT
        [txt] => google-site-verification=o3EMam8yBGo1yEjyybIiZcOunGHOQKpo8JmOtp9n1BU
        [entries] => Array
            (
                [0] => google-site-verification=o3EMam8yBGo1yEjyybIiZcOunGHOQKpo8JmOtp9n1BU
            )
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => TXT
        [txt] => google-site-verification=rdWtMbplKjbRHGr2dNONfwkqithlUvjr3u6i8QEz_mo
        [entries] => Array
            (
                [0] => google-site-verification=rdWtMbplKjbRHGr2dNONfwkqithlUvjr3u6i8QEz_mo
            )
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [host] => stackoverflow.com
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 300
        [type] => TXT
        [txt] => v=spf1 ip4:198.252.206.0/24 ip4:192.111.0.0/24 ip4:52.38.191.241 ip4:35.190.247.0/24 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:108.177.8.0/21 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 include:_spf1.stackoverflow.com ~all
        [entries] => Array
            (
                [0] => v=spf1 ip4:198.252.206.0/24 ip4:192.111.0.0/24 ip4:52.38.191.241 ip4:35.190.247.0/24 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:108.177.8.0/21 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 include:_spf1.stackoverflow.com ~all
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: It would help if you show some sample output from $dns

Comment: @MosheGross No problem, just added that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope below code may help you

```php
<?php
$dns = dns_get_record("stackoverflow.com");
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Host</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>TTL</th>
        <th>Extra</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach($dns as $dnsset) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $dnsset["host"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dnsset["type"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dnsset["class"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dnsset["ttl"] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php 
                        foreach($dnsset as $extrasetkey => $extrasetvalue) {
                            if(!in_array($extrasetkey, ['host', 'type', 'class', 'ttl'])) {
                                // If your data has extrasetvalue as array type also add conditions
                                // here and loop through them also
                                echo $extrasetkey . ":" . $extrasetvalue . "<br/>";
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like there's something wrong with the second `foreach` in your code.  It just displays like this:  https://i.imgur.com/VqzbArq.png